# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in Eclipse could not be instantiated

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android programming. Here is the issue I'm facing:-

I followed the xml code for toolbar from http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html and applied into Eclipse. I received this message:

"The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details."

May I ask any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: did you add the support library to the project?

Comment: Could you guide me on how to add the support library the project?

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html for information

Comment: Followed the guide given and had the support library updated to 21.0.2; and it is working for now. Thanks!!

Comment: [The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26575815/6521116)

Comment: I solve it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30749068/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Android 22, then make your MainActivity extend from `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`.  Then rebuild your gradle project and voila!

The only other possible solution I found is to switch SDK version to 21 in the upper-right (green android guy) of the Preview window.

Comment: after doing that I had to "clear the cache" too  and than it worked :)