# Error on view XML Layout Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

After creating a project already face longer get an error in the layout XML, the minimum version SDK is 15 and the target is 23 to buildToolsVersion the API version is 23.0.2

The depencies is:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

And the error in Layout:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image]

Style XML

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And the Style of API 21

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you post your `style.xml` file? Maybe you should change the base theme of your app's theme to something like: 
`parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

AFAIK design support library depends on AppCompat Support libraries

P.S. I can't comment yet so I am writing it as an answer

Comment: Hey, I Added the Style XML files

Comment: I just tried to create a new project and I think it contains the same components coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, Toolbar, etc. and it does render correctly without problems. You may try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29921076/3469686