# error when adding support design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

error when adding support design renderring problems occure then adding library , and using API 26 , and i already added maven in reporesetires and added dependencies but same problems.
tryed to to clean and rebuild same problem.
tryed to invalidate cashes same problem.

this is my codes.

Main_Layout

```
Faild to instiantiate one or more classes
The following classes could not be instantiated
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, 
  Clear Cache)
```

Gradle Module

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mac.floating"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
   }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and still having same problem , any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**your appcompact and design library version need to same.**

just change this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`26.0.1`** .

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** .

Comment: this is screen shot of the problem

Comment: @MohammadHassan oh..its bug probably. Select API LEVEL 25 or 23  from `preview`section

Comment: I changed the API version to 25 having same problem

Comment: @MohammadHassan Same problem for 23 ?

Comment: @MohammadHassan got the point . Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752383/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-toolba and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too

Comment: I tryed the solution of the link u gave me  before posting the question did not work too. Sorry

Comment: I alredy have the latest version of android studio

Comment: @MohammadHassan Check android studio version

Answer (score 0):

Your appcompact and design library version need to be the same:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

First change this

```
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

to :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
```

After that invalidate caches and restart , then clean project and rebuild it.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
transitive = true
```

Comment: share your exception details

Comment: this is screen shot of my details Exception

Comment: go to File > Invalidate Cache & Restart

Comment: i tryed to remove the library and i just added maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        } the problem shows same without any library of what my problem is

Comment: While this [code may answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.