# Android: What type of problems does project cleaning solve?

Tags: android, android-studio, rebuild

There are many types of programming errors like **syntax**, **logical**, and **runtime** errors and each one has a mechanism to solve it.
Cleaning project in **Android Studio** also solves other types of errors that occur in the project.
But what are the specific project problems that **cleaning project** can be used to solve? Many says clean project but when to clean the project?

Comment: An example, clean ,build and sync with gradle solve me [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too/38552537#38552537) problem :

Answer (score 0):

What 3 things i experienced,

1.When u do clean, it removes the binaries inside build folders
2,Clean removes the build folders contents.
3.clean removes all build artifacts.

Comment: So what are build artifacts?

Comment: Build artifacts are files produced by a build

Answer (score 0):

You should clean the project when the issue is related to the build of the project. This especially includes code generation with Android Studio and Annotation processors.

Also it should be done as last resort when you're out of ideas; just to be sure before asking for help.