# The following classes could not be instantiated - android.support.v7.widget.toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

I'm trying to figure this out for few days... read any answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too), but without success...

After I generate navigation drawer from android studio, I receive this error: "The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar"

The app works without crashing, but the layout designer of Android Studio reports rendering issue.

please help me to finally figure this out.

**exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:692)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:298)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:229)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:176)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:206)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:371)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**NavigationDrawer**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ActivityDataList"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_data_browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_violation_browser"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_violation_browser_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_data_browser.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ActivityDataList">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_violation_browser" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What version Gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: @lionscribe `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2`

Comment: I assume that this question is not a duplication since the accepted answer does not solve the problem...

Comment: Please make sure the Android Plugin is up to date.

Comment: Indeed not a duplicate as far as I can tell. @PYPL reports that their app runs correctly, and only the designer in Android Studio gives the error. The linked "duplicate" gets the error at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your build.gradle

```
android { defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the question again. See that that setting is already there

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that far in the question. I will leave the answer, for it may help the next person who doesn't have the line...