# While adding 26.0.0 in android studio - make erros

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering, android-support-library

Following error is occuring while ading new Support lib to studio i.e., 26.0.0

Error in rendering

> The following classes could not be instantiated: -
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show
>   Exception, Clear Cache)

Comment: can you add your gradle dependences here? thanks :)

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    
}

Comment: So possible duplicate try read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too

Comment: Tryed

Clean project
Rebuild project
Sync Gradle

But not working