# android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextview Failed to instataniate

Tags: android

i am having problem, failed to instantiate one or more classes.Following classes cannot be instantiate .
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextview

There it is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_comment_owner_display"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too

Comment: these all anserws didnt work for me @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 0):

**AppCompatTextView** was added in **appcompat-v7:22.1.0**

Please check you appcompat version. You have to update your gradle file with this.

Comment: i have latest version of appCompat in gradle com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2

Answer (score 0):

clean/Rebuild project from Android Studio,it might help.
If it doesn't try to invalidate caches and restart android studio.

Comment: try all these things :( @himel

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done,
Try adding the dependencies in your **build.gradle(Module:App)**
please check the version according to your app

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code in your layout

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        />
```

because i see no AppCompatTextView in your layout.