# Design Mode getting an exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated to Android-Studio 3.0.1 but I'm getting this error when I try to work in design mode

```
 The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.
  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.
  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.TintableBackgroundView
```

I allready tried reload, resync, rebuild. Use diferent sdk version to shoe the view

This is a screencap

[image]

**EDIT**
Source code of the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Activities.Acty_Main"
    tools:showIn="@layout/main_acty"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nest"
        android:background="@color/mailReadBack">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/mainView">
                 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lay_ContactList"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/loading">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/prgBar"
                    android:text="@string/loding" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.casa.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
//        targetSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix 'devs'
            versionNameSuffix '.devs'
            debuggable true
//            minifyEnabled true
//            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha2'
}
```

I'm downloading build-tools 27.0.3 but I have poor internet conection, maybe my problem is with the support libraries

Comment: always post your code as text and also why there are multiple namespace imports and enter between first line and swipe, remove them

Comment: update build tools for your project [ latest would be best]...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too)

Comment: I allready tried the solution posted and selected there and not working

Comment: Show me your build.gradle

Comment: Did you change `compile` to `implementation` in the build.gradle file?

Comment: no, it was inserted there by the Android-Studio