# layout editor render issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-editor

I'm new to Android Studio and started using it just 2 days ago. I downloaded the latest version and everything should be updated. Upon following the 'Build your first app' tutorial in the android website, I came across an issue when starting to use the editor as described here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui

I followed the steps described, but I get a rendering error:

The following classes could not be instantiated:

- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer

- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView

- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar

I have done absolutely nothing except the steps described in that tutorial.
I tried changing a theme, and then the error disappears and the preview displays the "Hello World", but when I run it on an emulator or my device, I see a different layout than the one seen in the preview of the new theme.
I don't really care what theme to use at this point, so helping me with either the 1st problem (the render error) or the 2nd (the layout showing wrong) is ok.
Thanks!!!

Comment: could you post your layout code, editor version of layout and output version of layout ?

Comment: and of course check your support libraries, all are installed or not.

Comment: @SudheeshR of course, but can you please tell me where I see the editor version of layout and output version of layout?. Also, what do you mean by checking the support libraries? (sorry, as I said I'm new to this)

Comment: editor version is the layout you are seeing in your android studio layout's visual design tab, and layout code means the code in the code version. And output is the layout you seeing in your emulator/phone. Support libraries can be found in settings>system settings>android sdk>sdk tools. Check that you've installed necessary android sdk tools and support repository.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30749068/8244632) may solve your problem.